# How to access a rest api in the local network using node js and express

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I have created a REST server using Node.js and express, but i am having trouble connecting to the server on a separate machine. The server machine and client machine are on the same local network.

This is my code for the server

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const imageUpload = require("./routes/imageUpload");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
    next();
});

app.use("/imageUpload", imageUpload);

app.listen(PORT, "0.0.0.0", () => {
    console.log("Running at port " + PORT);
})


router.get("/getFilename", (req, res) => {

        res.status(200).json({
            status: "recieved"
        });
 });
```

Upon using postman on the server machine the get request works fine even if using the machine IP address in the network(192.168.0.104:3000/imageUpload/getFilename).

On a separate machine in the network the postman will give an error of *There was an error connecting to 192.168.0.104:3000/imageUpload/getFilename*. so i am unable to connect to the API, How do i fix this? Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is rather in network settings, not in nodejs or express.

Did you try `ping 192.168.0.104` your server? If it works most likely you need to manually open port `3000`.

Try google how to open a port on a server for the OS your are using on that machine.

Comment: it works ! i am running the server on ubuntu and the comand _sudo ufw allow 3000_ did the trick.